# Google Analytics API - Cant add services after having authenticated

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Within the google console I have created Credentials for an API Key - Type Server and for Oauth with Type Other.

For the developer key I am using the API Key Credentials and for the client id/secret I am using the Oauth Credentials

I am using the php sdk for the google analytics api:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Schedule GA');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setUseObjects(true);

$ganalytics_settings = wp_get_custom_field_for_current_user('ganalytics_settings', 'ga_settings');

$ganalytics_settings['google_api_key'] = 'c0f3d189e82938128ndoea1a426ee4e264e4b0b0';
$ganalytics_settings['google_client_id'] = '17381202384367-gejnedh2aijuq1660f0lvl5uvj6roloo4.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$ganalytics_settings['google_client_secret'] = '**Secret key**';

$client->setClientId("17381202384367-gejnel2aijuq1060f0lvl5uvj6roloo4.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$client->setClientSecret("QclsDKOSLcsrbpJD_KLbIUtQ");
$client->setDeveloperKey("c0f3d189e82938128ndoea1a426ee4e264e4b0b0");
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client); //the error occurs here!!!

// Setting Access Token

$access_token = $ganalytics_settings['google_access_token'];
if ($access_token) {
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);
}
else {
    if ($ganalytics_settings['google_auth_code']) {
        $client->authenticate($ganalytics_settings['google_auth_code']);
        $ganalytics_settings['google_access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        // update_option('ganalytics_settings', $ganalytics_settings);
        ga_settings_exists_else_update();
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Cant add services after having authenticated
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Does your error message mention anything about scope? one thing that looks strange to me is that you have not set the scope. Also [This Question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397815/google-exception-with-message-cant-add-services-after-having-authenticated) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a scope first, example:

`$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);`

[This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) tutorial might help you in the future.